# working with global variable in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, global-variables

I have two view in same controller need to display first view's value in second view. I did it by session but i want top do this using `Configure::write()` or variable How can i do.

```
public function index() 
{
    Configure::write('workinghrs', '5');
}
public function view() 
{
    $this->set('price', Configure::read('workinghrs'));
}
```

it is not working. 
I also tries this

```
public $workinghrs;
public function index() 
{
    $this->workinghrs = "3";
}
public function view() 
{
    $this->set('price', $this->workinghrs);
}
```

but i am still unable to get value both are giving empty value.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a variable to persist across requests you need to use session. Anything you set using `Configure::write()` is in-memory and lost once that particular request finishes.

Comment: because he is using index()? what if you use it in bootstrap file? and how to use it with database?